# django admin app obscured when urls.py refers to any other app

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, django-urls, django-authentication

this seems to be a misunderstanding on my part of how the urls config works in django.  I thought that the first regex that matches is where it gets 'dispatched', but if I have others in the urls list, it goes to them instead of the first.

The contents of project's `urls.py` when the admin site is accessible:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        #url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
        #url(r'^index', include('limbo.urls')),
        #url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
        # url(r'^limbo/', include('limbo.urls')),
        #url(r'edit/', include('limbo.urls')),
    ]  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

but when I un-comment the 1st, 2nd or last comment-out lines, I get an error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

any thoughts?

for example, if I un-comment the line that says `url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),`, I get the error I stated.
`api/urls.py` contents:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?:addUse\.?[html]{,4})?$', views.addUsageHistory, name='addUsageHistory'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and the 
In the traceback, I can see it seems to originate with this file:
`/home/ec2-user/limbo/limboenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html`
and a ways down the stacktrace (second from bottom), i can see that in `/home/ec2-user/limbo/limboenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py`, the variable `pattern` is set to `'(?:addUse\\.?[html]{,4})?$`, which is one of the values in `api/urls.py`.  Why would it have ended up in api/urls.py at all?  it should have gone to admin.site.urls before it ever saw `r'^api/'`

Answer (score 0):

as is so often the case, I figured it out after beating my head against a wall for so long, then as soon as I post a question on SO, I figured it out.  for future reference, using `?:` in the beginning of a regex in an app's `urls.py` is very dangerous.  I changed my app urls.py to not have it and it all works as expected.  see my udpated `api/urls.py` here:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^addUse.html$', views.addUsageHistory, name='addUsageHistory'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```